# Can't modify document root's value on apache - keep getting /var/www

Tags: php, linux, apache, config, virtualhost

I've just started working with ubuntu 13.04 and I'm trying to work locally on my website's files.

Even though I've created a virtual host with my project's url & modified RewriteBase to this path on my htaccess as well.

My problem is with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (it's keep staying `/var/www` and not `/var/www/mysite`) and relative paths..

Thank you for your help.

Virtual host:

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mysite.com

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: show some code and what different options you tried.

Comment: You have a problem with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], noted, but what is the problem? What have you tried? Have you looked into the php.ini?

Comment: Post us your apache vhost config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

after editing your config, type this in your ubuntu terminal:

`sudo a2dissite mysite && sudo a2ensite mysite`

then

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: can you tell what is the name of the file you're editing. is it `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default` or something else instead of default?

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite

Comment: tnx tenstar but I'm keep getting this 404 for this test css file: http://localhost/css/style.css

Comment: after entering: sudo service apache2 restart, I'm getting:

Comment: getting what? where is the css folder located on your comp. ?

Comment: Reloading web server config                                                                                                                                                                               /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
httpd not running, trying to start
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'graceful' failed.The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: the css is in localhost/mysite/css/style.css

Comment: does this help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name

Comment: did you forget to type sudo

Comment: or try this: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: yea.. my bad sorry :-)

Comment: okay, any more problems :-) ?

Comment: nope. just my main problem that the document root isn't changing :-) tnx tenstar

Comment: even after the restart?

Comment: check my edit, i forgot the final slashes

Comment: yea, still the same.. I'm wondering if I should re-install php & apache

Comment: reinstalling php and apache wont help with virtual hosts

Comment: try putting the slash even before the document root? not sure if it works but lets try

Comment: Maybe move this to a chat room?

Comment: maybe deleting the default file in sites-available?

Comment: no dont delete, try: sudo a2dissite default

Comment: @ChristianGärtner we cant move this to chat room since user2553832 has only one reputation

Comment: and after `sudo a2dissite default` dont forget to restart

Comment: it worked!! tenstar you're amazing! thank you! tnx everyone

Comment: sure thing, tnx for your help.

Comment: Then accept it bro! click on the check mark beside my answer!

Comment: just to be sure, we've basically disabled the default one right?

Comment: yes we have disable the default one! to test type: `sudo a2dissite default` again and it will tell that it is already disabled, if it is already disabled

Comment: so if I want to add another site, I just need to create another virtual host such as this one? cause now localhost is pointing to the localhost/mysite. tnx

Comment: yes you can, for more help check this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Virtual_Hosts accept my question bro!